# ASP.Net MVC-4 bootstrap date-time-picket not rendered properly with Editor Templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, mvc-editor-templates

I have a web application build using ASP.Net MVC-4. I'm using the Bootstrap plugins and scripts in the application.
I'm having an issue rendering the date-time-picker with the editor template.
Below is the code of my date-time-picker editor template:

```
<div class="date-time-picker input-group">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Value, new { data_format = shortDatePattern + " " + shortTimePattern, data_val_requiredif = Model.RequiredIfDynamicErrorMessage, @class = "form-control" })
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Then i have initialized the date-time-picker as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".date-time-picker").datetimepicker({
            format: '@shortDatePattern  @shortTimePattern',
            locale: moment.locale('@language')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below are the variables used in the above script:

```
@{  string shortDatePattern = CultureHelper.GetDateTimeFormatInfoForCurrentCulture().ShortDatePattern.ToUpper();
    string shortTimePattern = CultureHelper.GetDateTimeFormatInfoForCurrentCulture().ShortTimePattern;
    shortTimePattern = shortTimePattern.Replace(@"tt", @"A");
    string language = CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture().TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
}
```

The editor templates are displayed inside a modal window. When the application is run, i'm partially able to see the date-time-picker widget and the rest is overlapped by the editor templates displayed above or below the Date-time-Picker editor templates.

Below pictures can be used to depict the same:

[image]

[image]

I'm using bootstrap version 4.15.35

I have tried using :

```
widgetPositioning: {
                horizontal: 'auto',
                vertical: 'auto'
            }
```

But it didn't work well with all possibilities for horizontal and vertical.

It would be really great if anyone could provide some suggestions regarding the same.

Comment: does it have anything to do with z-index?
i am not sure about it!

Comment: @PrashanthBenny: Tried Z-index as well.. still result is the same.

Comment: have you tried collapsible option like a dropdown and collapsible menu as in the dropdowns